# How could I set the url of microsoft emotion api by javascript

Tags: javascript, azure

I use following javascript

```
document.getElementsByName("Image.Url")[0].placeholder = "waha"
```

setup the value of the url [of the microsoft emotion webpage](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/cognitive-services/emotion/?cdn=disable), but the results I got is "light text".

[image: Real results]

Problem of "light text" is the webpage will not consider your input value as a valid url.

The result I need is normal text(if you input your text manually, color of the text will become "deeper") as following

[image: Expected results]

Comment: Replace `placeholder` with `value`, e.g.: `document.getElementsByName("Image.Url")[0].value = "waha"`

Comment: @IronGeek Thanks, this solve my problem, neat and clear. Could you put your comment at answer?It would be better if you could explain why the value work even I cannot see it by "Inspect element" of firefox

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using the wrong attribute:

> document.getElementsByName("Image.Url")[0].placeholder = "waha"

The [placeholder](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_placeholder.asp) attribute specifies a short hint that describes the expected value of an `<input>` element. It's the *light text* displayed in the `<input>` element before the user enters a value.

For setting the (initial) value of an HTML `<input>` element, you need to use the [value](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_value.asp) attribute, e.g.:

> document.getElementsByName("Image.Url")[0].value = "waha"

---

You could find more information on HTML `<input>` Tag and its attributes: [here](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_input.asp)